# Find range of 'a' for which the eqn. has at least one real solution.

Tags: trigonometry

If $\cot^{2} x + \csc x - a = 0$, then find the range of $a$ for which the given equation has at least one real root.

After simplification I arrive at:

$ y^{2} + y - (a+1) = 0 $ where $y = \csc x$

I solved for $D>0$ but that doesn't get me any far. The given solution is $[-1,\infty)$. Can anyone help me out... thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Firstly,

$$\Delta \ge 0 \implies 1+4(a+1) \ge 0 \implies a \ge -\dfrac{5}{4}$$

- Secondly,

$$|y|=|\csc x| \ge 1 \implies
\left| \frac{-1 \pm \sqrt{4a+5}}{2} \right| \ge 1$$

$$\implies -1-\sqrt{4a+5} \le -2 \quad \text{ or}
\quad -1+\sqrt{4a+5} \ge 2$$

$$\implies \sqrt{4a+5} \ge 1 \quad \text{ or} \quad \sqrt{4a+5} \ge 3$$

$$\implies a \ge -1 \quad \text{ or} \quad a \ge 1$$

(Using ***or*** because we need "at least one real" only)

> Combining $$-1 \le a < \infty$$